# 2sxc Blog app search only index page 1

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Using 2sxc Blog app, the DNN only indexes whatever is on first page of Blog page.

Second page onwards is not indexed, hence doesn't show in search results.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks alot @iJungleBoy for help.

For anyone else encountering this issues here's the solution:

Amend the visual query to create another stream example "SearchIndex"

[image]

Once thats done, amend the query within your template which gets all the list items and has paging.

```
@functions{

    // Prepare the data - get all categories through the pipeline

    public override void CustomizeData()
    {

    }

    /// <summary>

    /// Populate the search - ensure that each entity has an own url/page

    /// </summary>

    /// <param name="searchInfos"></param>

    /// <param name="moduleInfo"></param>

    /// <param name="startDate"></param>

    public override void CustomizeSearch(Dictionary<string, List<ISearchInfo>> searchInfos, ModuleInfo moduleInfo, DateTime startDate)
    {

         foreach (var si in searchInfos["SearchIndex"])
    {
        si.QueryString = "post=" + AsDynamic(si.Entity).UrlKey;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good question, and it's probably something we haven't thought about yet. Google doesn't care, but the internal search would probably "respect" the paging and only pick up the first page.

I can think of a few quick-fixes but they would be tricky to explain here. Please open an issue on the blog app on github.